# MySQL latin1_swedish_ci newline to <br>

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to convert a MySQL entry about like this:

```
Vorraum, WohnkÃ¼che, 2 Schlafzimmer, Badezimmer mit Badewanne, WC, Kellerabteil

WohnkÃ¼che:

Die neue EinbaukÃ¼che ist mit GeschirrspÃ¼ler, Backrohr mit Ceranfeld, Dunstabzug und KÃ¼hlschrank mit groÃŸzÃ¼gigem Gefrierfach ausgestattet. Der Raum bietet genÃ¼gend Platz fÃ¼r eine gemÃ¼tliche Wohnecke und einen groÃŸzÃ¼gigen Essplatz.

Schlafzimmer:

Beide Schlafzimmer sind mit einem schÃ¶nen Parkettboden ausgestattet. Ein Schlafzimmer ist etwas kleiner und bietet sich daher als Schrankzimmer oder Kinderzimmer an.

Badezimmer:

Das groÃŸzÃ¼gige Badezimmer ist mit einer Badewanne mit Duschbrause ausgestattet. GenÃ¼gen Platz fÃ¼r eine Waschmaschine und eventuell sogar einem Trockner ist vorhanden.

WC: ist separat vom Badezimmer.
```

It's converted with latin1_swedish_ci
So I'm trying to convert it like this :

```
Vorraum, WohnkÃ¼che, 2 Schlafzimmer, Badezimmer mit Badewanne, WC, <br><br>WohnkÃ¼che:<br><br>Die neue EinbaukÃ¼che is
```

But it doesn't convert however I try....
I tried php `nl2br($row['other'])` and `str_replace('\r\n', '', $row['other'])`

If anyone knows what could help me please tell me.

Comment: Please post correct code that you have tried. `nl2br str_replace('\r\n', ' ')` is invalid.

Comment: I tried php nl2br($row['other']) and str_replace('\r\n', '', $row['other'])

Comment: So you want `<br>` but also remove the newlines?

Comment: exactly And I forgot to say that in the replace i just replaced with nothing because it wasn't changeing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double quotes for `"\r\n"`.

You can also try this two methods:

```
echo str_replace(["\r", "\n"], '', nl2br($str, false));

echo preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/", '<br>', $str);
```

which will remove all Windows, Unix and Mac newlines.